# How to dynamically insert a form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a page in which i want a form to be dynamically inserted according to datalist value, without reloading the page

```
<form action='#' method='get'>
    <input list="category" name="category">
    <datalist id="category">
        <option value="Home">
        <option value="Car">
        <option value="Mobile">
    </datalist>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

For example if a person select Home, so the Home form should be shown at the bottom of the data list.

Any one have an idea how to do it?

Comment: There are many ideas, what is your idea? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Where is the HTML for the generated form (or where are the elements that make up the generated form) coming from?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Displaying elements based on select box choice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11627510/displaying-elements-based-on-select-box-choice)

Answer (score 1):

You have many options. You can insert them as a string using `innerHTML`

```
document.getElementById("id_here").append(string); //or innerHTML = string; where string = your code above!
```

Or you could take another route and dynamically assemble a form using `createElement`.

```
var x = document.createElement("form");
x.id = "derp";
document.body.idtoappendto.appendChild(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

I think this will be simple solution

```
$('#submit').click(function () {
    var cat = $('#cat').val();
    $('#'+cat).show();
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dFYKG/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Create a html file which contains your form or multiple html files containing one form each and in the page where you want to display the form write some ajax request based on which page the user is and call the corresponding form file and get its html and display it where ever you want.

for example in home page you want homeform.html to be displayed then create homeform.html in the directory and in home.html write an ajax function which fetches the homeform.html and display it on your home.html page.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply doing this using below code..

First of all set form id attribute with the same name of category value & initially hide all forms using `style="display:none"`. Then

```
 $("input[type='submit']").click(function () {
        var category = $("input[name='category']").val();
              $('#'+category).show();
  });
```